# Looking for image that goes around a contact in the contacts application

Tags: android, image

In the contacts app, from 2.0+ , in the list you can see a border around each contact image.

(look at the image)
http://thetech24.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Google-Android-2_0_thetech24.com.jpg

I have looked around the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts) for the contacts app, but coundn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for this one:

http://github.com/cyanogen/android_packages_apps_Contacts/blob/eclair/res/drawable-hdpi-finger/quickcontact_photo_frame.9.png